# dplyr to output class data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I can summarise a data frame with `dplyr` like this:

```
mtcars %>%
group_by(cyl) %>%
summarise(mean(mpg))
```

To convert the output back to class `data.frame`, my current approach is this:

```
as.data.frame(mtcars %>%
group_by(cyl) %>%
summarise(mean(mpg)))
```

Is there any way to get `dplyr` to output a class `data.frame` without having to use `as.data.frame`?

Comment: Wrap your first call in `str`: `Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame'`, or `is.data.frame`: `[1] TRUE`.

Comment: what about ddply in the plyr package? I believe this is its purpose

Comment: @Arun I frequently find myself converting back to a data frame to get rid of the extremely irritating (at least to me) printing behavior (suppressing columns) at the console.

Comment: @joran You could always override the print method `print.tbl_df <- print.data.frame`

Comment: main motivation behind this question is that the object outputted by dplyr retains its groups, which has caused me confusion when using that object in subsequent dplyr calls

Comment: If you just want to end the chain by dropping groups, could you just finish the chain with `%.% ungroup()`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments you might not need to convert it since it might be good enough that it inherits from data frame.  If that is not good enough then this still uses `as.data.frame` but is slightly more elegant:

```
mtcars %>%
   group_by(cyl) %>%
   summarise(mean(mpg)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   as.data.frame()
```

**ADDED** I just read in the comments that the reason you want this is to avoid the truncation of printed output. In that case just define this option, possibly in your `.Rprofile` file:

```
options(dplyr.print_max = Inf)
```

(Note that you can still hit the maximum defined by the `"max.print"` option associated with print so you would need to set that one too if it's also too low for you.)

**Update:** Changed `%.%` to `%>%` to reflect changes in dplyr.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what G. Grothendieck mentioned above, you can convert it into a new dataframe:

```
new_summary <- mtcars %>%
   group_by(cyl) %>%
   summarise(mean(mpg)) %>%
   as.data.frame()
```