# R plotting for loop group_by mutate Error in stripchart.default(x1, ...)

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, group-by, dplyr

I'm having difficulty plotting a `for` loop after I use the `mutate` and `group_by` commands from `dplyr` package. on a dataframe. What I don't understand is I have no problem with the plotting loop before I use the `group_by` command. I get the error

> Error in stripchart.default(x1, ...) : invalid plotting method

after using it though.
Can anybody explain this please or give a solution using `dplyr`?

Reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)

df<- data.frame(id=rep(1:4,each=30),
                      newt=rep(1:30,4),
                      fitted=runif(120, 120, 170))

somePDFPath = "C:/Users/some.pdf"
pdf(file=somePDFPath)  
par(mfrow = c(2,2))   

for (i in unique(df$id)) {  

  plot(df[df$id==i, "newt"], df[df$id==i, "fitted"],
             main = paste("Plot of", i))  # Give each a title
}
dev.off()
```

This works fine and creates the pdf.

If I now create a new variable using group_by and rerun a get the error. I thought including `ungroup()` would get rid of any issues?

```
df<- data.frame(id=rep(1:4,each=30),
                newt=rep(1:30,4),
                fitted=runif(120, 120, 170))

df<-df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(derivative = c(NA,diff(fitted) / diff(newt))) %>%
  ungroup()

somePDFPath = "C:/s.pdf"
pdf(file=somePDFPath)  
par(mfrow = c(2,2))   

for (i in unique(df$id)) {  

  plot(df[df$id==i, "newt"], df[df$id==i, "fitted"],
       main = paste("Plot of", i))  # Give each a title
}
dev.off()
```

> Error in stripchart.default(x1, ...) : invalid plotting method

Comment: It doesn't look like the plot command likes a data frame table.  Adding "df<-as.data.frame(df)" before the loop solves the problem.  Maybe someone else can provide a more detailed answser.

Comment: A few months late but anyone looking to understand @Dave2e answer. The dataset is class str: Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame' when group_by is used. It must be converted to data.frame, this can also be done at the end of the group_by command %>%  as.data.frame(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967942/dplyr-to-output-class-data-frame